# console error:Uncaught TypeError: require.config is not a function in magento2

Tags: magento2, requirejs

[image][image]

```
Uncaught TypeError: require.config is not a function
    at requirejs-config.js:18
    at requirejs-config.js:19
    at requirejs-config.js:757
(anonymous) @ requirejs-config.js:18
(anonymous) @ requirejs-config.js:19
(anonymous) @ requirejs-config.js:757
(index):36 Uncaught TypeError: require is not a function
    at (index):36
(anonymous) @ (index):36
(index):83 Uncaught TypeError: require.config is not a function
    at (index):83
```

Comment: You can run command 
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --theme Magento/backend  language_backend  -f

Comment: note: language_backend   what language are you using in admin and admin login page

Comment: Example :  php  bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --theme Magento/backend en_US nl_NL it_IT -f

Comment: Ok..I will check using this commnd

Comment: Mgs/claue is the theme used..then in the commnd php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --theme Magento/backend en_US nl_NL it_IT -f  in place of "theme" what text i used?

Comment: You can view-source browser check or Ctrl + U find static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/  the language you are using will be displayed please get the word from the language then and replace it with the command line

Comment: Example : https://demo.com/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/extjs/resources/css/ext-all.css

Comment: you can run command line :  php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --theme Magento/backend en_US  -f